What is the difference in concrete things between being and existing, or is there none?
I am supposing that being and existence must correspond to principles in concrete things, else the notions of being and existence are false precisely because they are attributed to things. So what exactly is it in things (for example, a cat or dog) that being has but existence does not and vice versa? Note that I am not merely looking for the conceptual difference (obviously, they are different conceptually), but the real difference in things (i.e., in re) if such a difference exists... pun not intended.

Please remove the unintelligent Community Bot

Paraphrasing OP: what exactly is it in things (for example, a person) that being has but existence does not?
Heidegger distinguishes the 'subjective' existence of a person (the Being of Dasein) from the objective existence of things, which he calls "presence-at-hand".  A person can be present-at-hand even to theirself, but their Being is what makes them alive so to speak.

The 'essence' ["Wesen"] of this entity [i.e. Dasein] lies in its "to
be" [Zu-sein]. Its Being-what-it-is [Was-sein] (essentia) must, so
far as we can speak of it at all, be conceived in terms of its Being
(existentia). But here our ontological task is to show that when we
choose to designate the Being of this entity as "existence"
[Existenz], this term does not and cannot have the ontological
signification of the traditional term "existentia"; ontologically,
existentia is tantamount to Being-present-at-hand, a kind of Being which is essentially inappropriate to entities of Dasein's character.
To avoid getting bewildered, we shall always use the Interpretative
expression "presence-at-hand" for the term "existentia", while the
term "existence", as a designation of Being, will be allotted solely
to Dasein. GA 2, H.
42

For presence-at-hand Heidegger generally follows Kant's definition for the objective existence of things, as given in The Critique of Pure Reason :-

Through the actuality [i.e. objective existence] of a thing I certainly posit more than
possibility, ... [While] possibility was merely a positing of a
thing in relation to the understanding (to its empirical use),
actuality is at the same time its connection with perception. B287


Being [objective existence, in this context] is obviously not a real
predicate, i.e., a concept of something that could add to the concept
of a thing. It is merely the positing of a thing or of certain
determinations in themselves. In the logical use it is merely the
copula of a judgment.
B626

The copula is the connection of idea/possibility plus (evidenced by) sense perception data, thus constituting the thing's existence for the observer [Dasein].
Treating objective existence as 'knowledge', when knowledge corresponds to the facts this is truth.  However establishing the facts is tricky since the effects a thing might reveal may be misleading as to what the facts of the matter are.  Heidegger calls this the twofold concealment.

Concealment can be either a refusal or merely an obstructing. We are
never really certain whether it is the one or the other. Concealment
conceals and obstructs itself. ...
The essence of truth, i.e., unconcealment, is ruled throughout by a
denial. This denial is, however, neither a defect nor a fault – as if
truth were a pure unconcealment that has rid itself of everything
concealed. If truth could accomplish this it would no longer be
itself. Denial, by way of the twofold concealing, belongs to the
essence of truth as unconcealment. (The Origin of the Work of
Art
(1935-1936), pages 30–31)

So we can't be certain of the truth of the existence of things. Hence in Contributions to Philosophy (1936–40) Heidegger writes:

Is there indeed truth? How? If truth were not, on what would stand
even the mere possibility of the "why"? Does the why-question already
confirm the fact that there is truth, that truth must be in some way
or other? GA 65, §236.
Truth

Returning to the Being of Dasein, concealment and unconcealment are considered to occur in The Clearing, which is where one's view of the world takes place.

In the midst of beings as a whole an open place comes to presence.
There is a clearing. Thought from out of beings, it is more in being
[Existenz] than is the being [entity]. This open center is, therefore,
not surrounded by beings. Rather, this illuminating center itself
encircles all beings – like the nothing that we scarcely know.
The being can only be, as a being, if it stands within, and stands out
within, what is illuminated in this clearing. Only this clearing
grants us human beings access to those beings that we ourselves are
not and admittance to the being that we ourselves are. Thanks to this
clearing, beings are unconcealed in certain and changing degrees. But
even to be concealed is something the being can only do within the
scope of the illuminated. (The Origin of the Work of
Art,
page 30)

So we come to one of Heidegger's most tangible elucidations of Being: "the clearing itself is being".

metaphysics recognises the clearing of being either solely as the view
of what is present in “outward appearance” (ἰδἐα) or critically as
what is seen in the perspect of categorial representation on the part
of subjectivity.  This means that the truth of being as the clearing
itself remains concealed for metaphysics. [163] However, this
concealment is not a defect of metaphysics but a treasure withheld
from it yet held before it, the treasure of its own proper wealth.
But the clearing itself is being.  Within the destiny of being in
metaphysics the clearing first affords a view by which what is present
comes into touch with the human being, who is present to it, so that
the human being himself can in apprehending (νοεἴν) first touch upon
being (θιγεῑν, Aristotle, Metaphysics Θ, 10).  This view first draws
the perspect towards it.  It abandons itself to such a perspect when
apprehending has become a setting-forth-before-itself in the
perceptio of the res cogitans taken as the subiectum of certudio. (GA9 Pathmarks, Letter on “Humanism” (1946) pages 252-253)

Being's relation to nothing is that we see nothing of Being.  We see the phenomena; the unconcealed-concealed beings that constitute the world.

The nothing is the "not" of beings, and is thus being, experienced from the perspective of beings. (1949 preface to On the Essence of Ground, Pathmarks, p. 97)


Beyng is nothing "in itself" and nothing "for" a "subject." Only
beingness can appear as this sort of an "in itself" and can do so only
in the form of an effete φύσις [phusis/Nature], i.e., as ίδἐα, the καθ' αὐτό ["for
itself"], something represented, an object. An extreme confinement in
objectivity befalls all attempts to find "being" and its
"determinations" (categories) in the manner of something objectively
present. (GA 65, §270. The essence of beyng)


I'm not really able to make this sense of this. -- Some of the metaphors (clearing, unconcealment = discovery = Entdeckung) make some sense, but I trust Plato who said we should distrust pictures and distrust poets. I deeply distrust the rhetoric and tendentious formulations in Hs philosophical poetry. For instance the last quote implicitly seems to advocate irrationalism, an anti-empirical-science stance. When I see this I also cannot help but wonder how this relates to Hs collaboration with the nazis.

Re. "the last quote implicitly seems to advocate irrationalism, an anti-empirical-science stance." It's not anti-science. It's setting the foundations for the positive sciences: e.g. "Basic concepts determine the way in which we get an understanding beforehand of the area of subject-matter underlying all the objects a science takes as its theme, and all positive investigation is guided by this understanding." GA 2, ¶ 3

Ok, I admit I'm being kind of fussy here, but... if not anti-empirical-science, why then "extreme", "confinement" and why is determinations put inside double-quotes?

The problem in the last quote – e.g. "Beyng is nothing" – is indeed elusive. If you become inclined to tackle it I would recommend Jacques Derrida's Heidegger: The Question of Being and History – a canny précis of Being & Time. The conclusion is conclusively inconclusive: "'Being' cannot indeed be conceived as an entity; enti non additur aliqua natura: nor can it acquire such a character as to have the term "entity" applied to it." GA 2, 4

Re. "extreme confinement in objectivity" – we are confined to our point of view; we don't have God's view point, (or the view from nowhere). Being, as very tricky to articulate, if even possible to intuit, resists determinations like the Tâo that cannot be named. Hence both 'being' and 'determinations' are in quotes, because we can't be sure what they are.  E.g. even the idea that Being 'is' breaks normal language.

Thanks for the reference - but I'm not able to read Derrida. Heidegger, I was able to read 40 yrs ago. But with Nietzsche I have to say: "Jetzt entcheidet unser Geschmack gegen die Philosophie, nicht mehr 'unsere Gründe'" (he said, "gegen das Christentum", but the sentiment is the same). Confronted with what I perceive as nonsensical language, my only rational stance is to reject it out of hand, not caring whether my stance is accused of being irrational... :)

Or perhaps I should try reading Derrida... Some other time.  Too many other things to do.

A criticism of the Nazi era, aside from Heidegger's provincialism, is that he later expanded his own idea of Dasein in a Völkisch manner to mean people in a collective sense, also as if by strengthening the clarity of the German language it would lead to clearer thinking. My interest is personal phenomenology, although inevitably we live in a collective culture. Mit-sein, Being-with one another.

Re. "nonsensical language". I agree, but I also like the bafflement of trying to read Derrida's more playful stuff. Heidegger's material is esoteric from the outset, nevertheless I try to explain it in simpler terms for fun.


I am supposing that being and existence must correspond to principles in concrete things, else the notions of being and existence are false precisely because they are attributed to things. So what exactly is it in things (for example, a cat or dog) that being has but existence does not and vice versa?

I'm assuming that with being you are referring generally to 'being a dog' or 'being a cat', in other words, to applying a predicate to particular, concrete objects (objects that we can perceive through our senses). If so, then 'being' is equivalent to 'a predicate applying (to some object)'.
So, the sentence 'This is a cat' attributes the property of 'being a cat'
to the creature at hand, the creature pointed out by the demonstrative term 'this'. 'Being a cat' could further be explained in various ways. For instance, by referring to some criteria (has soft fur, purrs, pointy ears, cute, loved by every one on the internet, and since a few days ago also, hates J.D.Vance, and the like).
Alternatively, it could be the speakers' intention to point out 'this' object, the object at hand, as a prototypical example of a cat ('being a cat'). ("What is a mudskipper?" "This is a mudskipper.")
Existence is in most current accounts construed as the existential quantifier. So, "There is a mouse" is construed as "There is an x such that x is a mouse". "Santa Claus does not exist" as "There is no x such that x is the one and only person answering to the name 'Santa Claus' and performing all the wonderful miracles told about him".
The extential quantifier is normally applied in reference to some given domain: "There is an x in the set of reals such that _", "There is an x in our empirical world such that _".
So being is equivalent to asserting a predicate or to having a property  or attribute. But existence (as existential quantifier) does not add any new properties or attributes to any object. It's also not strictly necessary to assume that the domain is totally given; that is, it's not necessary to assume that any specific object in the domain already exists in the domain. What "There is an x such that _" claims is that the domain over which we are quantifying is not empty, and that at least one x in the domain has the predicated property (or properties). Also, the statement could only be considered to be meaningful if the speaker (if challenged) is able to actually point out such an x. (In an intuitionist interpretation of mathematics, for instance, the existential statement is only meaningful if equivalent to having a method of finding or constructing such an x.)
As to a 'difference in things', it's not really clear to me what you mean by 'in things'. Existence as "being located in/being findable in the world" (or in some world, some domain) when said of some particular object

"Mitzi, my cat, exists"

would mean something like

"I can point out to you a creature, called 'Mitzi' (and that creature is a cat and it is mine)."

So "existence" is here translated into a possible method of finding something. This could be construed as an attribute of the object ('being present and findable in the world') but in the usual explanations of these
concepts this is not done. It doesn't add anything specific to the descriptive characteristics of that object, merely points at a pragmatic relation between the speaker/listener, the object, and the world. (It could perhaps be relevant in some contexts; if we cannot take the domain of discourse for granted or if we need to explicitly refer to different domains of discourse - for instance, the world of objects we can perceive versus an imagined world of imagined objects. Concrete objects vs abstract objects.)
The conundrums of being and existence seems typical for languages in the Indo-European family. In classical Chinese there were never problems since the different senses of 'to be' (copula/predication versus quantification) were represented by very different grammatical constructions. The following is a quote from A.C.Graham, considered to be one of the greatest Western sinologists of the last century:

In Indo-European languages the nominal sentence, even in languages such as Greek were it is common, is easily interpreted as a verbal sentence with the verb 'to be' understood. What an object is, its essence, laid down in its definition, appears in the Aristotelian tradition as part of its 'being', as objective as its existence even when clearly distinguished from it. In Chinese however the word 是 shih, 'this', being a demonstrative, simply picks out one thing from others as the one in question; there is no 'essence', merely the existence (有 yu) of the thing with all its properties. The world has a certain object, and if the object has, for example, four legs, teeth, a tail, colour (white, black), no horns, it fits the name 'horse'.

(A.C.Graham, Later Mohist Logic, Ethics and Science, p26)
In classical Chinese, the existential quanitifier is expressed with 有 yoǔ ('have', 'there is', 'is present'; negated with 無 wǔ, 'have not', 'there is no', 'is absent'):

（天下）有馬 - (World) there-is horse(s) - Horses exist (in the world)


（天下）無鬼 - (World) there-is-no ghost(s) - Ghosts do not exist (in the world).

The copula is expressed in various different ways; the most common one is with the end-sentence particle 也 yě (negated by the verb 非 feī):

是馬也 - this a-horse ye - This is a horse


馬也 - a-horse ye - It is a horse


非馬（也） - it-is-not a-horse (ye) - It is not a horse

As aside: It's interesting that the ontological argument for God's existence that may seem coherent when formulated in Latin (or other Indo-European languages), cannot be translated into (classical) Chinese without losing the appearance of coherence. (I cannot find the reference to Graham's analysis; if someone has that, please comment).
